# Print specific string 123456789 to a specific format 12xxxxx89 in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to print a string in specific format like :

```
<?php

$var  = "123456789";

echo $var; //expected output 12xxxxx89;
?>
```

Want to show first two and last two characters from string and show others in `x` format.How can i do that ?

Comment: Is the value of $var always numeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy

```
echo substr_replace($var, str_repeat('x', max(strlen($var) - 4, 0)), 2, -2);
```

This should handle strings at or below 4 characters in length too.

Demo ~ <kbd>[eval.in](https://eval.in/218495)</kbd>

Links to functions:

- [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/function.substr-replace.php)
- [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-repeat.php)
- [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strlen.php)
- [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/function.max.php)

Answer (score 1):

`echo substr($var,0,2).str_repeat('x',strlen($var)-4).substr($var,-2);`

Comment: As mentioned on [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794020/print-string-in-specific-formate-in-php/26794070#comment42163156_26794153), you need to watch out for strings that are less than four characters long. `str_repeat()` will trigger a warning if passed a number less than zero

Answer (score 1):

#### View this <kbd>[CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tIrgQ6)</kbd>

#### Code

```
<?php

    $var = '123456789';
    echo "Original: $var \n";
    
    $number = max(strlen($var) - 4, 0);            // Find length 
    $x = str_repeat("x", $number);                 // Get Number of time x       
    
    $final =  substr_replace($var, $x, 2, -2);     // Replace x from 2nd position to last -2 postion
    echo "After:" . $final;                        // Final String

?>
```

#### Result

```
Original: 123456789
--------------------
After:12xxxxx89
```

Comment: Gotta watch the original string length. `str_repeat()` throws a warning if the second arg is < 0

Comment: Check fist if $x is at least one then welcome to substr_replace function use **max() function** to check length.

Comment: Yes, I know. I had already done so in my answer 10 minutes prior to your edit

Comment: @Phil oohhhh i see at now. because i m spend time to solving this thing i love i dont see what post on here. if u don't like my behavior sorry from my side.

Comment: No problems at all. The explanations in your answer make it great

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var  = "123456789";

echo maskCharacters($var); //expected output 12xxxxx89;

function maskCharacters($str){
    $l = strlen($str);
    if($l<5){
        return $str;
    }else{

        return substr($str,0,2).createNumberOfX(strlen($str)-4).substr($str, $l-2,$l);
    }
}

function createNumberOfX($c){
    $x = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
         $x .= "X";
    }
    return $x;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var  = "123456789";
$strarry = str_split($var);
for($i = 2 ; $i< count($strarry)-2;$i++)
$strarry[$i] = "x";
$var = implode('',$strarry);
echo $var;
?>
```